# Accessing Outlook 2010 Mail Folder in C#

Tags: c#, outlook, add-in

I am working on an Outlook Add-In, and recently switched to C# for sake of familiarity (I am a Java man at heart). At this point, I am simply trying to iterate through a mail folder and print the subject of each message to the console, mainly as a way to make sure everything is working alright so far. Whenever I run it, however, I receive the following error:

> *Could not complete the operation. One or more parameter values are not valid.*

#### Exception Text:

> System.ArgumentException: Could not complete the operation. One or more parameter     values are not valid.
>          at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpaceClass.GetFolderFromID(String EntryIDFolder, Object EntryIDStore)
>      at OutlookAddIn2.ThisAddIn.ThisAddIn_Startup(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>      at Microsoft.Office.Tools.AddInImpl.OnStartup()
>      at Microsoft.Office.Tools.AddInImpl.AddInExtensionImpl.Microsoft.Office.Tools.EntryPoint.OnStartup()
>      at Microsoft.Office.Tools.AddInBase.OnStartup()
>      at OutlookAddIn2.ThisAddIn.FinishInitialization()
>      at Microsoft.Office.Tools.AddInBase.Microsoft.Office.Tools.EntryPoint.FinishInitialization()
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.DomainCreator.ExecuteCustomization.ExecutePhase(ExecutionPhases executionPhases)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.DomainCreator.ExecuteCustomization.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.Interop.IExecuteCustomization2.ExecuteEntryPoints()

#### Loaded Assemblies:

I am somewhat baffled by this, as this is the precise method recommended by Microsoft on MSDN to have a user select a folder. I have included my source, please let me know if you have any thoughts. Thanks for taking the time to read this post, and for being willing to help out!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;

namespace OutlookAddIn2
{
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            //Get application namespace and grab the original folder object
            Outlook.Folder pickFolder = (Outlook.Folder)Application.Session.PickFolder();

            //Outlook.Folder mrFolder = Application.Session.GetFolderFromID(pickFolder.EntryID, pickFolder.StoreID) as Outlook.Folder;

            foreach (Outlook.MailItem oMailItem in pickFolder.Items)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(oMailItem.Subject);
            }
        }

        private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        #region VSTO generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InternalStartup()
        {
            this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
            this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, sorry for the poor formatting, the auto-parser is doing something dreadful to my code...

Comment: Thats what we have a Robert Harvey for!

Comment: The guy that formatted your post :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this, of course, if you want Inbox folder:

```
Outlook.Application app = new Outlook.Application();

Outlook.NameSpace ns = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");

Outlook.Folder folder = app.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox) as Outlook.Folder;
```

Comment: I will try that as a debug option, I am actually trying to get at a folder that is on the same level as the Inbox (easier to use that way).

Answer (score 1):

Tray this:

```
 public static Folder FOLDER_1;
 public static Folder FOLDER_2;
 public static Folder FOLDER_N;

/// <summary>
        /// Hilo que lee el archivo de datos PST del OUTLOOK
       private static void readPst()
        {
            try
            {
                Application app = new Application();
                NameSpace outlookNs = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
                MAPIFolder mf = outlookNs.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderTasks);


                string names = mf.FolderPath.Split('\\')[2];



                Folder fMails = getFolder(fCarpetasPersonales.Folders, "Inbox");



                FOLDER_1= getFolder(fMails.Folders, "FOLDER_1");
                FOLDER_2= getFolder(fMails.Folders, "FOLDER_2");
                FOLDER_N= getFolder(fMails.Folders, "FOLDER_n");

//TO DO... For example:  foreach (object item in fMails.Items)



     private static Folder getFolder(Folders folders, string folder)
        {
            foreach (object item in folders)
            {
                if (item is Folder)
                {
                    Folder f = (Folder)item;
                    if (f.Name.Equals(folder))
                    {
                        return f;
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should debug or add trace statements to see the values of `pickFolder.EntryID` and `pickFolder.StoreID`. Without a valid `EntryID` or `StoreID` it will throw this error.

```cs
Trace.TraceInformation("EntryID: {0}\tStoreID: {1}", pickFolder.EntryID, pickFolder.StoreID);
```

You should check if `pickFolder` is null should the user click the **cancel** button.

Also, if you are letting the user pick a folder, you don't need to select the folder again via `GetFolderFromID` - you already have a reference to it.

Comment: I did figure out that the double-reference bit was redundant, its good to know that I was indeed on the right track with that. I am still rather new to this language and Visual Studio 2010 (am used to Netbeans/Eclipse) so I don't really know how to utilize trace statements(am used to this being done while stepping through code in the IDE). Is there a built in tool that handles this? Thanks again!

Comment: I looked around the internet, and one post suggested that this might be a problem with symbols (DLLs) not loading in the project. Sure enough, under the Modules window in Visual Studio, NONE of the requisite symbols were being loaded, or had even been downloaded. I got them from the Microsoft Symbol Server, and then changed the Build language to C# explicitly. I now routinely get the PickFolder dialog, but still get the same error after selecting a folder. Have a question in the VS debug forum, but please let me know if you think of anything else. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear whether you stepped through the code in the debugger as @SilverNinja pointed out.  Ensuring that StoreID and EntryID are valid is important.

There are another few possibilities:

Your Outlook PST is slightly corrupt.  Try scanPST and see if that helps.

Also, you would think that the pickFolder enumeration would be smart enough, to skip these, but do you have other items at the top level of folder tree than folders?  I've actually had this problem with enumerating contacts and having non-contact items in my contacts folder.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment, I had to drop the project and move on to other things and was never truly able to figure it out. I was indeed stepping through the entire code, but I fear I may have missed something while doing so. I do appreciate the effort, and I hope to revisit this at some later point. You all are amazing!